# What are all the modes to query a database in

Tags: boolean

I  know boolean mode, but what are the others.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Search Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)